# Get netstat Info in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, networking, visual-studio-2010

Is it possible to get information from the netstat command in Silverlight? How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that this is only possible when running stand alone Silverlight apps that run from the desktop with elevated privileges. It is not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the [Microsoft Silverlight Analytics Framework](http://msaf.codeplex.com)?  It contains a component from Nedstat.